# Getting defining function based on alias `z' error everytime open the terminal

Tags: zsh

Getting this bellow error every time when opening my terminal (ZSH using)

```
(eval):10: defining function based on alias `z'
(eval):10: parse error near `()'
```

Also why getting this error after every time execute anything via terminal

```
bgnotify_end:5: condition expected: 0x0
```

Why getting this and how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I do not know what zsh is, but a backquote and an apostrophe are very different characters, also known as grave and acute.

Comment: info: https://www.zsh.org/

Comment: Sounds like a messed up definition in your ~/.zshrc

Comment: Check every parameter. Even remove the plugin https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/z

Comment: Try `zsh -x ~/.zshrc` to see what's going on.

Comment: Tried but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone finding this because of error:

```
(eval):10: defining function based on alias `z'
(eval):10: parse error near `()'
```

My solution was to add `function` at the function declaration.
See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/6723#issue-313463147

Answer (score 0):

After checking several things, finally found the issue it came for

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

which I have removed and reinstall again. Now everything is fine. Thanks, everything.